# Is it possible to match tuple types using classTag?

Tags: scala, reflection

If A is a TypeTag the following condition will try to match the inner types of Tuple2 too, i.e String and Int.

```
if (typeOf[A] == typeOf[Int])
    ...
else if (typeOf[A] == typeOf[Tuple2[String, Int]])
    ...
```

If A is a ClassTag the following condition will match up to Tuple2 but not the inner types.

```
if (classTag[A] == classTag[Int])
    ...
else if (classTag[A] == classTag[Tuple2[String, Int]])
    ...
```

Is there a way to match the inner types of a tuple using ClassTag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `ClassTag`, no. A `ClassTag` only stores information about the *class*. In `Tuple2[A, B]`, the type parameters `A` and `B` are not class information, they are *type* information. That is, `Tuple2` is the class, and `Tuple2[A, B]` is the type. Thus `TypeTag` should be used to compare. *Actually*, the `Type` contained in the `TypeTag` should be used to compare.

Therefore, if `A = (A1, A2)`, then `classTag[A]` will only know that `A` is `Tuple2`, but will know nothing of `A1` and `A2`.

Another note, when comparing type tags you should use `=:=`, which will de-alias them before comparing.

```
scala> type IS = (Int, String)
defined type alias IS

scala> typeTag[IS] == typeOf[(Int, String)]
res18: Boolean = false

scala> type IS = (Int, String)
defined type alias IS

scala> typeTag[IS] == typeTag[(Int, String)]
res19: Boolean = false

scala> typeOf[IS] == typeOf[(Int, String)]
res20: Boolean = false

scala> typeOf[IS] =:= typeOf[(Int, String)]
res21: Boolean = true // only =:= produces what one would expect on comparing types
```